# Why didn't Beerus stop Buu?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

Beerus is the God of Destruction in Universe 7, and his main job was to maintain balance in the universe by destroying planets. If Buu had gone around blowing planets, wouldn't it disturb the balance of the universe? We all know from the Battle of Gods that Beerus is **much, much stronger** than Buu. Then why didn't he do something?

Comment: Doesn't this belong on the Anime SE?

Comment: Isn't some anime sci-fi or fantasy?

Comment: @Justin Alexander there was a dbz tag. That's why I posted it here.

Comment: I guess what I should've said is your question is more suited for Anime SE.  This site does accept anime questions because they can be sci-fi and fantasy, but in my experience the anime site will answer your question more readily (and maybe even more thoroughly.

Comment: I believe this may have something to do with Beerus's propensity for sleeping quite a long time. As I recall, per Battle of Gods, he's been sleeping since at least before the start of the events of the DBZ anime.